# Error:No value accessor for name "selectedText"

Tags: angular, angular5, karma-jasmine

While I am writing unit test for component creation in angular, this error is shown

> "error: no value accessor for form control "selectedText".

If I replace `<p-editor>` with `<input>` ,its working. But I don't want to do that. Kindly help me with the code explanation if possible.

**app.html**

```
<p-editor [ngModel]="selectedText" formControlName=""selectedtext">
```

**app.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

...

constructor(public Form: FormBuilder) {}

this.eventForm = this.form.group({
  selectedText: [''];
})

...
```

**app.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule,FormGroup,FormBuilder} from '@angular/forms'

describe('AppComponent', () => {
      let component: FirstpageComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture < FirstpageComponent > ;

      beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          declarations: [AppComponent]
        })
        imports: [FormsModule, HttpModule]
          .compileComponents();
      }));

      beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
      fit("should be defined", () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
      })
```

Comment: if i replace <p-editor>with <input> tag,its working fine.But i dont want to do that.

Comment: what is `p-editor`. it's a selector from any of your components or a selector from a library?

Comment: its from library

Comment: Import component 'p-editor' in the spec.ts file also. For example: import { PEditorComponent } from './p-editor.component';

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if you make all your **imports** and **modules registrations** correctly.

**First**:

Check if in your `app.module.ts` `FormsModule` is registred inside the `@NgModule` decorator like:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ FormsModule ]
)}
```

**second**

Make sure all neccessary primeng modules are registred.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome KISHORE R,

You cant give formControlName to p-editor because it's not formcontrol element it's a component. Just you need to this

```
<p-editor [ngModel]="selectedText">
```